# How do I analyze text that doesn't have a separator (eg a domain name)?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a bunch of domain names without the tld I'd like to search but they don't always have a natural break in between words (like a "-"). For instance:

```
techtarget
americanexpress
theamericanexpress // a non-existent site
thefacebook
```

What is the best analyzer to use? e.g. if a user types in "american ex" I'd like to prioritize "americanexpress" over "theamericanexpress". A simple prefix query would work in this particular case but a user then types in "facebook" but that doesn't return anything. ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of the case including yours, `Standard Analyzer` is sufficient. Also, it is default analyzer in ElasticSearch and it provides `grammar based tokenization`. For example:
`"The 2 QUICK Brown-Foxes jumped over the lazy dog's bone."` will be tokenized into `[ the, 2, quick, brown, foxes, jumped, over, the, lazy, dog's, bone ]`.

In your case, domain names are tokenized into list of terms as `[techtarget, americanexpress, theamericanexpress, thefacebook]`.

> Why query search for `facebook` doesnot return anything?

Because, there is no `facebook` term stored in the dictionary and hence search result return no data. Whats going on is that ES try to find search term `facebook` in the dictionary but the dictionary only contain `thefacebook` and hence search return no result.

**Solution:**

In order to match search term `facebook` with `thefacebook`, you need to wrap **wildcards around your search term** i.e. `.*facebook` will match `thefacebook`. However, you should know that using [regex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) will have a performance overheads.

Other workaround is that you can use [synonyms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms.html). What synonyms does is that you can specify synonyms (list of alternative search terms) for your search terms. e.g. `"facebook, thefacebook, facebooksocial, fb, fbook"`, with these synonyms, you can provide any of search term from these synonyms, the it will match with any of these synonyms. i.e. If your search term is `facebook` and your domain is stored as `thefacebook` then the search will be matched.

Also, for prioritization you need to first understand how [scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) work in ES and then you can use **[Boosting](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/06/22/tuning-relevance-in-elasticsearch-with-custom-boosting/)**.